# Flash CS4: Actionscript 3.0 How to load images from a file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image-loading

I currently can load images from a url but what is the script for loading and image from a file in my harddrive?

```
ti.border = true
ti.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);

function onInput(event:TextEvent):void
{
    if(ti.text.search('a')!=-1) load_image("http://i54.tinypic.com/anom5d.png", "ottefct");
    else if(ti.text.search('b')!=-1) load_image("http://i53.tinypic.com/2dv7dao.png", "rnd");
    else if(ti.text.search('c')!=-1) load_image("http://i51.tinypic.com/m8jp7m.png", "ssd");    
}

var loaded_images:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

function load_image(url:String, id_name:String)
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.name = id_name;
    var url_req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadingComplete);
    loader.load(url_req);
}

function onLoadingComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    var img_name:String = evt.currentTarget.loader.name
    var spr_box:Sprite = new Sprite();
    spr_box.addChild(evt.currentTarget.loader);

    spr_box.mouseChildren = false;
    spr_box.doubleClickEnabled = true;

    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, rotate);
    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK , unrotate);

    //Shouldn't really hard code this here
    spr_box.width = 124;
    spr_box.height = 180;
    spr_box.x = 430;
    spr_box.y = 425;

    // - Since this isn't a class, I'd do this instead:
    //spr_box.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, resize_img);

    this.addChild(spr_box);
    loaded_images[img_name] = spr_box;
}

//Because this event function lets you control individual image dimensions
/*
function resize_img(evt:Event):void
{
    switch (evt.currentTarget.name)
    {
        case "ImageOne":
            evt.currentTarget.width = 250;
            evt.currentTarget.height = 250;
            break;
        default:
            evt.currentTarget.width = 180;
            evt.currentTarget.height = 124;
            break;
    }
}
*/

function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.startDrag()
}

function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.stopDrag()
}

function rotate(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 90
}

function unrotate(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To load an image from the client machines hard drive you have to use the [FileReference class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html).  This allows you to open a standard file select box, the user to select a file, and that file be loaded into Flash as a ByteArray.  You can then use Loader.loadBytes to load as a DisplayObject as usual.

Answer (score 0):

As shanethehat says, to load a file from the clients hard drive, in a solution intended for use on the web, you have to use the FileReference class and have the user pick the file.

So that is probably the way you want to go, but since you ask about "loading an image from a file in **my** harddrive", if what you want to do only concerns your computer, where you develop and run the swf, you could also use a relative path to the file, or use the `file:` protocol instead of `http:`.